# Drupal 7 view to loop through store locations

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I am needing to setup a view in Drupal 7 that loops through content entries with fields. The content listing page will display teasers of each entry item with only the store name, address, suburb and phone number displayed. When the store name is clicked, I want the resulting page to display all details about the store. Could someone provide me insight on how to get this setup. I have a single content item with multiple field collections that works in a similar way, but it does not provide the click through functionality. It can be viewed here: http://endlessfitness.co.nz/swim-spa-retailers.

Answer (score 0):

For the view format instead of using teaser you can select fields. And then add those fields which you want to show. To make the titles clickable, when you will add the title field it will give an option to link it to the content.
Here is the fields format option.
[image]

And here is the field which you will need to add. The screenshot will have different fields than yours because I don't know what fields are there in your content type.
[image]

And here is the option to link title. So when you will add title field you will get this popup
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got that working, but now I struggle with how to access the data for the content, loop through it and display it within the view. I have setup the template file and it is being recognized, but unsure of what to do next.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand what you did. Can you please explain what you did and why/what template you created?

Comment: Drupal posted a message that had suggestions for view template files, so I created one to match the content I was adding using FTP. It is called views-view--swim-retailer.php. Now that it is created, I am needing to add the for loop to display all entries and have the titles linked to individual full pages. I sort of understand the render/print content functions, but not sure of how to properly implement it. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Views template files are used when you need to update the design of it. The loop and all other things will come from default templates. I think in your case you don't need a views template so you can remove it. Did you check my post as to how you can add fields to view. So you can decide which fields will show on your content list page. Regarding linking the titles, when you will add title field, it have option to link it to content for which I have put a screenshot also. Let me know if it is not clear to you.

Comment: I am confused. How would I properly display a list of content items with custom fields on one page and individual content items on single pages without using a view. How will Drupal know where to look? I have also have a specific DIV structure that needs to be implemented to style the output. Without a view, this seems impossible. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am not saying to remove the view. We will create the list using views itself. But what I am asking is to remove the view template. So the list page will be handled by views page while the individual store pages will be basically node pages which will be handled by drupal core.

Comment: Views provides different ways of adding list. And I am not asking to add custom fields. Those fields will be what your content type have.
As you say that your store will have a particular div structure then we will need a views template but there are different views template suggestions which address some particular part of the views display. So for example there is a style output template then there is a row style output template(which have the loop to show content) and then there can be field view templates for individual fields.

Comment: Here is a quick tutorial on overriding views template files https://www.interworks.com/blog/carmstrong/2013/02/27/quick-tutorial-overriding-drupal-views-using-templates
And this one
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/group/views_templates/7.x-3.x

Comment: Thanks for the URL. I should remove the custom tpl.php file that is stored in the views directory? Is this correct? How will Drupal know how to handle the code? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the custom tpl.php file of view. Actually views module have default templates inside of the module folder. So if you won't create any of the views template, it will use those default templates. But if you want to change the div structure then you can use targeted views template as explained in the tutorials I gave link to.

Comment: I have followed the instructions and have this setup: http://endlessfitness.co.nz/swim-spa-locations. The linked titles are displaying, but I cannot get the field collection items to display. It needs to mimic this style of page: http://endlessfitness.co.nz/swim-spa-retailers. What settings will I need to tweak in order for field collection items to display? Thanks.

Comment: For values of field collection you will need to add a relationship to that field in view. Here is a discussion on the same topic https://www.drupal.org/node/2804225
Let me know if you still have issue.

Comment: I am still not having much success. I have set it up, but now no content is being displayed. Any ideas?